# javascript keep sub navigation bar open on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a fiddle

jsfiddle.net/ExaLM/1

Now the sub navigation bar is closing on mouse leave event.

But if I hover on sub link bar then also sub link bar closes.

So what changes should I make in my code for that?

code is

```
          $(document).ready(function(){                     
    $("#main-nav li a.main-link").hover(function(){  

        $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                   
        $(this).addClass("active");                                        
        $("#sub-link-bar").animate({  
            height: "40px"                       
        });  
        $(".sub-links").hide();  
        $(this).siblings(".sub-links").fadeIn();  
    });  
    $("#main-nav li a").mouseleave(function(){  
        $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                                                       
        $(".sub-links").fadeOut();  
        $("#sub-link-bar").animate({  
            height: "10px"                       
        });       

    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExaLM/2/)

Basically, what you want is to avoid hiding the elements when the mouseleave event is fired. To do so, you could bind on both the `a.main-link` and its `<ul>` element, or you can do it like I did: bind your jQuery events on the whole `<li>` so `mouseleave` is not triggered until you leave both the main link or the sub-links, as it is contained in the whole `<li>`. I had to change `hover` to `mouseenter` to avoid it being fired repeatedly.

I also had to add some [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to avoid the animation repeating entirely every time the mouse gets out of the menu and bounce a few times before finally stopping. You should also remove the `.hide()` because sometimes when moving the mouse fast, the elements are still visible when they are hidden and it makes it look jerky.

I hope this is enough for you to figure out how to fix your menu.

Comment: mouseenter was a clver move!